# Find position in string where regular expression failed

Tags: php, regex

I'm using preg_match in php.  Is there any way to get the position of where the regular expression failed, or perhaps which character it failed on?

Comment: some code "where" and "how" it failed would help

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [`preg_last_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-last-error.php).

**Edit**:

Actually that won't tell you where it failed. It just returns error constants depending on the type of error. Try pasting your regex into [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/), and checking where it highlights red. I don't think regexpal supports lookbacks though so if you're using one it will be red as well. That doesn't mean there's an error there.